# Summing Counts of a wide variable once per subject

Tags: r, data.table

I have a subject dataset `subjects` that contains a set of variables corresponding to medications subjects have taken.  From that wide variable, I've created a unique set of all the meds in the dataset (Regardless of which specific variable it came from).
I want to find the subject count of each med, such that if a subject lists a med once or more that count is increased by one.

Below is a slow way of doing it, but I have 9 med variables and over 50,000 subjects.  Can someone help me figure out a more efficient way?  Thanks.

```
subjects <- data.table(
 med1= as.factor(c("NASONEX","ALBUTEROL","","BENADRYL","THEODUR")),
 med2= as.factor(c("","ALBUTEROL","ASBRON","NASONEX","MONTEKULAST")),
 medrecent= as.factor(c("MONTEKLUAST","","","THEODUR",""))
 )

 medvarnames <- c("med1","med2","medrecent")

 allmeds <- data.table(
 med=subjects[,unique(unlist(sapply(.SD,levels))), .SDcols=medvarnames],
 count=0
 )

 for(i in 1: dim(subjects)[1]){
 allmeds[, count := count +
 sapply(allmeds$med,function(.m){
 as.integer(
 any(.m == subjects[i,.SD,.SDcols=medvarnames],na.rm=TRUE)
 )
 })
 ]
 }

 allmeds
           med count
1:                 4
2:   ALBUTEROL     1
3:    BENADRYL     1
4:     NASONEX     2
5:     THEODUR     2
6:      ASBRON     1
7: MONTEKULAST     1
8: MONTEKLUAST     1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about

```
as.data.frame(table(unlist(apply(subjects, 1, unique))))
```

There might be faster methods but it does a decent job (~1.5 sec) on a 50,000-by-9 table like you mentioned.